# Website menu is centered but has one item under the rest

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I recently added two new menu items on my site in doing so the navigation bar looks like so.

```
                   |Item|Item|Item|Item|Item|Item|
                                 Item
```

as of right now I haven't been able to fix it. decreasing the font size did not help and none of the box alignments are changing it either.
This the code for that part of the menu

```
.primary-menu .pmenu {
margin: auto;
display: inline-block;
float: left;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
background: #fff;
```

and then the body of the header itself

```
body {
font-weight: 400;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 1.625;
margin: 0;
background-color: #eee;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afer visiting the link to your site you provided in a comment to the other answer: There is simply not enough horizontal space in that container to fit all the elements in one row!

So you can consider one of (or a combination of) the following options:

- Increase the `width` of `.content-wrap` (1320px should work, but makes all content elements wider).
- Decrease the left and right `padding` for the menu links (selector `.main-navigation ul li a`)
- Derease the `font-size` for the menu links (again, selector `.main-navigation ul li a`)